# delayed echo result

Tags: echo

I have a form where i add details for new participant then submit it with in my database and redirect it back to the form page and echo the details at the bottom of the page.

but right after i submit, when it comes back at the form page it doesn't echo the data. i still have to wait for about a few minutes then refresh the page to view the list of details.

i wonder why the echoing of data is delay?

what i did is i hard refresh (ctrl+f5) then i can see the update list. 
But is there a way where i dont have to hard refresh the browser?

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors? there are a lot of possibilities and if the code is not available to us then it might be hard to give the right answer. Please update your question with your code and it will be more likely that someone is able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to tell. Try looking at the HTTP headers (use Live HTTP headers add on for firefox) and see if the cache is involved in this delay.

Comment: im sorry im just new in this. can you show me how? i would appreciate it. i also ask one of my friend from outside to try to check the form, still same problem delay result and still have to hard refresh to view updated data.

Comment: @jonathan - Find the live http add on for firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/). It will give you the HTTP headers. See if any are to do with caching. You need to look at the HTTP spec (google it).

Comment: Wow! i finally got it! now i see where the problem is...
i remove this line 
===> if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    die('User id is not in session, blame the programmer');
    }
   
I don't know why but right now i'm not having delay on the output in my page right after i submit the form.